# How to install xnviewmp using package management aptitude `apt-get` on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: software-center, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

How to install xnviewmp using package management aptitude `apt-get` on Ubuntu 12.10?

Visiting https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xnviewmp/ and
clicking through to software center ends results in a not found error.

screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11744656/20130423-01.png

I have all the ubuntu software sources enabled, and the "partners"
sources as well.

Both apt-cache searches return no results as well.

`apt-cache search xnview` and
`apt-cache search xnviewmp`

I'm wondering If I'm missing something in /etc/apt/sources.list
Alternatively, how can I find something from either xnview.com or
apps.ubuntu.com that will show me what I could add to sources.list to
allow updating via "apt-get update".

I ended up installing the package using dpkg -i xnview...deb -- but
I'd like to understand what I'm missing in the above fails.

I asked on #ubuntu a few times and was just encouraged to install
using the *.deb .

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: I might be being a bit thick, but have you tried simply "sudo apt-get install xnviewmp" ?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu so I can't test, but it might have been removed from the repos (it's proprietary) and not from the website.

Comment: @somoso @Alex `E: Unable to locate package xnviewmp`

Comment: In that case, it isn't in the official repositories. If you really want a repository, there is a third party repository you can install by doing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway`,  `sudo apt-get update`, and then `sudo apt-get install xnview` but like the people on #ubuntu said, it is best if you just stick to the website debs until they provide a repository themselves.